# Dynamically update highcharts via setData for Yii-created Highcharts Widget

Tags: yii, highcharts, yii-extensions

Is it possible to update a highcharts chart using the `chart.series[i].setData` method if the chart has been created by the Yii extension? I have used highcharts before without Yii extension and able to reference my variables once I set the chart up via declared variable `var chart = ...`. I would just like to to able to call the setData methods for a Yii-created highcharts...this is current code for creating chart:

```
$this->Widget('ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget', array(
    'id' => 'shop_pie',
    'options' => array(
        'chart' => array(
            'backgroundColor' => '#efefef'
        ),
        'colors' => $colors,
        'title' => array('text' => 'Shop'),
        'plotOptions' => array(
            'pie' => array(
            'showInLegend' => 'true',
            'dataLabels' => array(
                'formatter' => 'js:function(){return this.point.y}',
                'distance' => -10,
                'color' => '#000'
            ),
        ),
        'series' => $results['series'],
    )
));
```

My ajax call to update the chart:

```
"$('#city_filter').on('change',function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ". $quotedUrl . ",
        data: { 'cities': e.val },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#name_span').text(data[0]);
            //chart.series[0].setData(data[1]); // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO BE ABLE TO REFERENCE THE CHART
        }
    });
});",
```

Many thanks in advance.
Andy

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console ?

Answer (score 2):

```
"$('#city_filter').on('change',function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ". $quotedUrl . ",
        data: { 'cities': e.val },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#name_span').text(data[0]);
            var chart = $('#shop_pie').highcharts();
            chart.series[0].setData(data[1]); // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO BE ABLE TO REFERENCE THE CHART
        }
    });
});",
```

referring to
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData

and example from that article
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/